# How can I run a function over a rolling window on each collective key in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am handling some event data, and I'd like to run a function that loops down an ordered list of values for a given key and return a value. I'm not sure how to do this, or if it's possible using Spark, and am hoping for a tip in the right direction.

Specifically, I have some event data, and I'd like to see when an arbitrary value appears multiple times within a rolling window.

An example of what I'm trying to do: Let's say I want to see how many times within my rolling window a value has appeared more than once, and to return the number of times that this has occurred. I'm thinking I'd have a queue that can expire old data, a map that contains the current data and its timestamps, and the number of times that this repeated appearance has occurred.

Assuming the rolling window accepts a timestamp difference of `10`:

`(user=A, value=10, timestamp=1)` -> Queue: `[(A, 10, 1)]`; Map: `{10: {1}}`; Repeated Appearances: `0`

`(user=A, value=20, timestamp=2)` -> Queue: `[(A, 10, 1), (A, 20, 2)]`; Map: `{10: {1}, 20: {2}}`; Repeated Appearances: `0`

`(user=A, value=30, timestamp=3)` -> Queue: `[(A, 10, 1), (A, 20, 2), (A, 30, 3)]`; Map: `{10: {1}, 20: {2}, 30: {3}}`; Repeated Appearances: `0`

`(user=A, value=20, timestamp=4)` -> Queue: `[(A, 10, 1), (A, 20, 2), (A, 30, 3), (A, 20, 4)]`; Map: `{10: {1}, 20: {2, 4}, 30: {3}}`; Repeated Appearances: `1`

`(user=A, value=10, timestamp=13)` -> Queue: `[(A, 30, 3), (A, 20, 4), (A, 10, 13)]`; Map: `{10: {13}, 20: {4}, 30: {3}}`; Repeated Appearances: `1`

I'm able to write this up in code for one group, but unsure how I can pass a function to a group of values in Spark. In this case, I'd want to pass all events for user "A" to a function that will return a result of `1`.

All thoughts appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could define an user defined aggregate function (say my_fn) and let it internally maintain the counts and emit the required count in the result. You can then define your group by condition based on the window and user id.

```
df.groupBy(window(...), $"user").agg(my_fn($"value")).writeStream....
```

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started with rolling windows, you'll have to implement the details of your logic yourself (unless I find the time to do it for you):

```
val w = Window.partitionBy("user").orderBy($"timestamp").rangeBetween(0, 10)
```

NOTE:

- Spark 2.1 [rangeBetween](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/WindowSpec.html) calculate the boundary based on the actual value of the orderBy expression
- The offset (positive in my example for a lookahead) is applied to the numeric column "timestamp". Spark 2.3 might have other options but I cannot test it at the moment
- Both startRange and endRange are inclusive

Example:

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("A", 10, 1), ("A", 20, 2), ("A", 30, 3), ("A", 10, 4), ("A", 40, 13), ("A", 50, 14), ("A", 1, 15))).toDF("user", "value", "timestamp")
df.show  // NOTE: I changed your data a bit to make the example more interesting 
+----+-----+---------+
|user|value|timestamp|
+----+-----+---------+
|   A|   10|        1|
|   A|   20|        2|
|   A|   30|        3|
|   A|   10|        4|
|   A|   40|       13|
|   A|   50|       14|
|   A|    1|       15|
+----+-----+---------+

df.withColumn("max", max($"value").over(w)).show
+----+-----+---------+---+                                                      
|user|value|timestamp|max|
+----+-----+---------+---+
|   A|   10|        1| 30|
|   A|   20|        2| 30|
|   A|   30|        3| 40| // 3 + 10 = 13(inclusive) => max value is already 40
|   A|   10|        4| 50| // 4 + 10 = 14(inclusive) => max value is already 50
|   A|   40|       13| 50|
|   A|   50|       14| 50|
|   A|    1|       15|  1| // max=1 because of look ahead (you can change this using negative range combinations)
+----+-----+---------+---+
```